# How can I more efficiently deserialize set data strings?

Tags: python, pydantic

I've written a Rust program that exposes it's JSON API in the form of JSON Schema and then using portions of that to create Python pydantic classes.

Where I'm stuck is that I have several JSON schema types that I could receive in the Python code and I'm rather inefficiently deserializing them.  A facsimile of the what's below is working, but I feel there has to be a better, more 'pythonic' way.

```
class DataType(BaseModel):
    pass

class ATypeData(DataType):
    ...

class BTypeData(DataType):
    ...

class CTypeData(DataType):
    ...

def deserialize_wired_json_str(json_str) -> DataType:
    json_data = json.loads(json_str)
    
    if 'a_type' in json_str:
        return ATypeData.parse_raw(json.dumps(json_data['a_type']))
    elif 'b_type' in json_str:
        return BTypeData.parse_raw(json.dumps(json_data['b_type']))
    elif 'c_type' in json_str:
        return CTypeData.parse_raw(json.dumps(json_data['c_type']))
    ...
```

... and by "set" I mean the types of string encapsulated JSON data is known to map to the defined `DataType` class variants.

Comment: By "set data strings", do you mean that a given string could be one of a specific set of pre-determined options? Or else *what exactly*?

Comment: Just use `ATypeData.model_validate(json_data['a_type'])` instead of going through the whole serialization/deserialization process twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance standpoint, you waste more time deserializing/serializing JSON than is necessary. Instead of

```py
ATypeData.parse_raw(json.dumps(json_data['a_type']))
```

you can just do:

```py
ATypeData.model_validate(json_data['a_type'])
```

Additionally, you can use a dictionary to simplify the cascading if-statements:

```py
data_type_mappings = {
  "a_type": ATypeData,
  "b_type": BTypeData,
  "c_type": CTypeData,
  # ...
}

def deserialize_wired_json_str(json_str: str) -> DataType:
  json_data = json.loads(json_str)
  data_type_name, data_value = next(iter(json_data.items()))
  data_type = data_type_mappings[data_type_name]

  return data_type.model_validate(data_value)
```